# Manipulating values in table from JSON using Jquery

Tags: javascript, jquery, json

I get all the rows in my table using Jquery in the following way:

```
var table = $.fn.dataTable.fnTables(true);
var nodes = $(table).dataTable().fnGetNodes();
```

I am interested in 2 columns in the table. One column is called ID, other is called value.
I have a JSON object which maps the ID with the value in the following way:

```
val mapping = {
    "XYZADZ": {"CALC_180":"74.91"},
    "ABCDED": {"CALC_180":"80.92"}
};
```

`XYZADZ` and `ABCDED` are the IDs and 74.91 & 80.92 the values. The values will always have CALC_180 before them.
The column name for ID is tID and for value, tValue.

If I have to insert a value in a particular row I usually do

```
$(nodes[0]).find('.tValue').text("$2000");
```

which inserts a value of 2000 in the row

However I am trying to do for every ID in the JSON object, update the corresponding value in the table. Is there a way to find the text in the column in the tID column?

```
<tr class="odd">
    <td class="tID">XYZADZ </td>
    <td class="tValue"> </td>
</tr>
```

In the "tValue" column I am trying to fill in values from the JSON (mapping).

Comment: Can you add the table HTML, to make your question more clear?

Comment: @arve0 Updated with example HTML

Answer (score 0):

You could do something like this to update the table:

```
$("tr", table).each(function(i, row) {
  var id = $(".tID", row).text()
  var val = $(".tValue", row)
  val.text(mapping[id].CALC_180)
})
```

**Edit**: Use the table variable, in case you have several tables in DOM.

Comment: What's the variable I used for ?

Comment: `i` is the index. So `0, 1, 2, 3, ...` depending on how many rows you have. It's not used in this example.

Comment: Hmm ok. In this case we aren't using the table stored in varibale table or nodes?

Comment: I've adjusted the example to use the `table` variable. We do not need the `nodes` variable.

Comment: what does the row variable do? Does the table pass all the rows to row one by one?

Comment: `row` is each `<tr>` in the table. I advise you to take a look at the documentation: http://api.jquery.com/each/